What happens if one has $N$ number of screens in a double slit experiment?
Imagine, in a double slit experiment (for electrons) we place $N$ number of screens. For instance, if we have observed the electron right after it passes through a hole (in the double slit), then we are sure that it will not produce an interference pattern. But instead of letting this electron strike on the screen, we let the electron pass through the hole on the projection screen. Since, the electron was destined to strike on the screen on a line in the center of the screen, we make $N$ holes in the screen such that they will let the electron pass through. This way we will have another source of electrons. Then we place another screen behind the first screen in parallel with this time with $(N-1)$ holes. This way we make a setup with $N$ number of screens which are placed in the front of a double slit, and that an electron source before it which is emitting electrons one-by-one.
Now, obviously in the first try the electron passing through one of the $N$ holes in the first screen is not 100%, but if we pass enough number of electron one-by-one, then there will be surely some electrons passing through one of the $N$ holes, maybe some of them end up going to the last screen where there are no holes.
Now the question, Since that we already have registered the state of the electron right after it passed through the double slit. Then, what are the chances that it will produce the interference pattern on either of the $(N-1)$ screens. Or, it wouldn't matter how many times we do the experiment, the state will be fixed since we have observed it. Or, the state will randomize right after it passes through the first screen (with $N-1$ holes), and will produce an interference pattern. If it doesn't produce any interference on the 2nd screen, then what's likely is that the screen may produce the interference pattern.

The electron is dumb, the EM field of all the holes in the screens (the apparatus) interacts with the EM field of the electron which influences the paths taken.

Each hole that you make in one screen will act as a source of electrons for the next screen. However, the intensity of this source will depend on where you place the hole. If you place a hole near a minimum of the interference pattern on the first screen, then very few electrons will pass through the hole; if you place a hole near a maximum then many more electrons will pass through the hole. So the interference pattern that you see on the final screen will depend on exactly where you have placed the holes on all of the previous screens.
